# Using .formula using vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying link to workbooks. Then Remove the link. The formula is working fine when the Full path is given but fails the moment a string is passed. In the below vba i'm trying to give the name of the location of the files from a cell value in Sheet1.

```
'Location of Template and Country
    Cntryloc = """" & Sheet1.Range("B5") & """"
    Debug.Print Cntryloc
    TempLoc = "" & Sheet1.Range("B11") & ""
    Finaltemplloc = Sheet1.Range("B17")

    i=2

   'Getting the name of excel Sheet
   CntryExcel = Sheet1.Range("C5")

   TempLoc = "" & Sheet1.Range("B11") & ""
   Workbooks.Open TempLoc & "\" & "Bank" & ".xlsx", True, False
   Workbooks("" & FName & ".xlsx").Activate
   ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="Tall.Trees"
   Worksheets("Template").Unprotect Password:="Tall.Trees"
   Worksheets("Template").Range("D14").Formula = "='&"["&CntryExcel&"]Dump"&"'"&"!"&"$A$" & i""
   ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink Name:=Cntryloc, Type:=xlExcelLinks
         Worksheets("Template").Protect Password:="Tall.Trees"
     ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password:="Tall.Trees"

    'Location for Final Output

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Finaltemplloc & "\" & Bank.xlsx
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Comment: You are trying to remove the link from where?

Comment: is Dump is a sheet name?

Comment: Yes Dump is a sheet Name and Im trying to remove the link to the Country File..The below formula is working but I wanted it to be dynamic, the below code works if put in above correct places:                                                                                       Workbooks.Open "Z:\TCRM=CCR\CountryRIR\TallTree\Templates\" & FName & ".xlsx", True, False
    Worksheets("Template").Range("D14").Formula = "='[country list.xlsm]Dump'!$A$" & i & ""
    
       ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink Name:="Z:\TCRM=CCR\CountryRIR\TallTree\country list.xlsm", Type _
        :=xlExcelLinks

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
Worksheets("Template").Range("D14").Value = "='[" & CntryExcel & "]Dump'!" & "$A$" & i & ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink & "Name:=" & Cntryloc & ", Type:=" & xlExcelLink
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Worksheets("Template").Range("D14").Formula = "='[" & CntryExcel & "]Dump!$A$" & "i"
```

that should fix the formula input

but check for `CntryExcel` to hold a workbook name and not a sheet name as per your comment preceeding its initialization (`'Getting the name of excel Sheet`)